# Is the following set non-empty?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I proofed that following set in the image is closed , we know if {C<sub>n</sub>} be a bounded sequence in R it should have converged subsequence with all that said can we say that the set in the image is non-empty? [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RaQc.png)
sorry that I posted the set as an image ,I could not paste it correctly , I appreciate if someone tell me how I can type math symbols easily here

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If $c_n=n$, the set will be empty

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as $\{ C_n \}$ has a convergent subsequence, you can take this subsequnce's limit (which exists because of convergence), and it will be an element of the said set.

Comment: Why is there a convergent subsequence? What if $c_n \to \infty$?

Comment: Because $\{ C_n \}$ is a bounded sequence.